# Table without lock won't query unless nolock hint included

Tags: sql-server, locking

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table that currently can not be queried on but seems to not have a lock against it.

Doesn't return:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Does return:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable with (nolock)
```

Inserts into the table also fail.

When I run `sp_lock`, I don't find any instances of locks on `myTable`. When I run the "Resource Locking Statistics by Object" report, I don't see any locks for `myTable`.

What other possibilities could there be that would keep a table from being acted upon?

Thanks.

Comment: Start the query and check blocking processes from sys.dm_exec_requests

Comment: There is no blocking_session_id populated.

Comment: Hmm, does it get a different plan with nolock? Maybe this is optimization issue and it would finish but just takes a long time

Comment: Maybe you have a hanging transaction that has locked the table? Strange you don't see any locks though. Obviously something is blocking you.

Answer (score 1):

Run sp_who2 and look at all the spids.  See if you still have a connection to the database that is still thinking your performing an insert/update/delete to the table.  If you find it, kill the spid and you should be able to query the table.