# Queries work only WITH (NOLOCK)

Tags: sql-server

I have found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054823/table-without-lock-wont-query-unless-nolock-hint-included), but the answer is not explained very well so I need your help. After I `exec` the `sp_who2` there are more then 70 records in the result. Some of them are started by my PC, but some of them are started by someone else because the table is located on a server that is used by multiple people in the company.

In the column called `COMMAND` in the result table, there is one record with `SELECT INTO` statement written in it and my PC is the host. Could that be the one that is causing the problem and how should I kill it?
Also, the status of  this command is `RUNNABLE`.

Comment: Go and grab sp_WhoIsActive from http://whoisactive.com/ .  It is written by Adam Mechanic and will tell you what processes are active and if there is blocking etc.

Comment: I could do that if the DB was mine, but since I am working in the big company I don't think I would be allowed to do that, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill it by calling `kill [132]` where `[132]` would be the SPID of the process. This may be left as a result of a transaction you have not yet committed, which you could find by running `DBCC OPENTRAN;`

Comment: `DBCC OPENTRAN;` returned next code `Oldest active transaction:
    SPID (server process ID): 66
    UID (user ID) : -1
    Name          : dev_KreirajKnjiziProv
    LSN           : (4528725:3947:1)
    Start time    : Nov  1 2017  4:01:21:587PM
    SID           : 0xfc5717486dc7714c8cfb239bb4ea5b0f`. What should I do next? Kill the SPID that is causing the problem?

Comment: I have found this `SPID` after calling the `sp_who2` but that is not the one that causes the problem, `LastBatch` for that `SPID` is after I found this problem. So the problem existed even before this `SPID` was created

Comment: Calling `kill 66` will solve your problem. Just be careful that you don't actually need that process to complete as it will kill it without prejudice.

Comment: You were right. The `SPID 66` was causing the problem, the application was run on another PC and when it was closed there, the problem was resolved. Thank you for help!